# Console View - Right Side Bar

Tags: console

How do I add, related list "New Button" to the right side bar of the Console view.
I tried adding it in the console console components of the page layout. But the realated list button appears for manager role and it does not show up for roles that report to manager. what am I missing here. How can i enable the new button for other other users that are reporting to manager. Please help. 
[image]

Now, If I have create permission I can see the related list button in the ride side bar. But, when I click on the button , nothing happens. What's wrong with the button..?  Can you please tell me the steps to add a related list button on the right side bar of the console view.                                                                      Steps I followed:
 1. on the case pagelayout --> added related list and also added new button for the related list.                                                                                            2. In the custom console components of case pagelayout --> sub tab components --> added related list.                                                                   3. But when i click on the button in the right side bar nothing happens  .       4. when i navigate down to the related list in details page, and click on the related list new button, it works fine.
5. why is it not working in the right side bar

Comment: It looks like some access issue, are they able to see a new button in list views or related lists of detail page?

Comment: If the user has access to create new records for that object, you should be able to see the new button else you won't see.

Comment: Yes .. the user don't have create permission for that object. Thanks lot

Comment: @SarathGarimella post your comments as an answer and Sandhya could accept that. This way others may get benefited seeing the questions/answers rather than moving through the comments

Comment: sure @SantanuBoral. I added it as an answer.

Comment: It's a salesforce Known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a salesforce known issue- [Standard components do not open in Knowledge One Right Sidebar Subtab Component when Case is opened in a Subtab from Account using custom code](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAhxQAG&title=standard-components-do-not-open-in-knowledge-one-right-sidebar-subtab-component-when-case-is-opened-in-a-subtab-from-account-using-custom-code)

> **Summary**: When opening a case record as the subtab of contact record and
>   when user has knowledge in the right subtab component, upon clicking
>   on any links it is not opening the sub related component like buttons
>   or records.
>
> **Workaround**: Open in the related list of the standard components parent
>   object.

Comment: you might want to link the known issue in your answer please, otherwise, its not very useful and others cannot vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has access to create new records for that object, you should be able to see the new button else you won't see.

Comment: Now, If I have create permission I can see the related list button in the ride side bar. But, when I click on the button , nothing happens. What's wrong with the button..?  Can you please tell me the steps to add a related list button on the right side bar of the console view.